# Cannot map <A-w> in insert mode in gvim?

Tags: vim

I want to map Alt+w  as below, it it seems it doesn't work like other key combinations, such as  which works well. What's the restriction for this key combination?

```
" below map doesn't work in gvim
inoremap <A-w> <C-o>w
```

Comment: Will the `<C-o>w` right-hand side appear in the output of `:imap`? Under which left-hand side?

Comment: Do you change `:set encoding=...` **after** defining the mapping? That's a common cause.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, as workaround, i mapped it as `inoremap <A-f> <C-o>w` and it works. I didn't change the encoding.

Comment: What kind of platform are you (Linux / Windows); does the shortcut work elsewhere? If you type `i<C-v><A-w>`, what / any character gets inserted?

Answer (score 1):

if `alt-w` opens your gvim menu, you can add this:

```
set guioptions-=m
```

Comment: Thanks. I already set this option in my vimrc, and there is no menu bar in my gvim Window, but the mapping of `<A-w>` still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows, try `set winaltkeys=no`

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows, but it seems this command still doesn't work.